# Retrieve gcloud Project createTime

Tags: gcloud

I'm searching how I can get the value "createTime" for the asset type "cloudresourcemanager.Project, which to my understanding reflects the creation time for a GCP project.

This data is available on GCP following : IAM & Admin > Asset Inventory > Resource > Asset type cloudresourcemanager.Project.

I found out how to retrieve info from this specific asset type. I'm actually using the following command :

```
gcloud asset list --project='my-super-project' --asset-types='cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/Project'
```

But the only info I get from this command is the value of the last updateTime and I don't find out where CreateTime is registered.

Thks

Comment: Ok, so in fact Project creation time is available using `gcloud projects describe`.

Comment: If you solved your own question, you should consider making your comment the answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @DazWilkin.

If you are searching for Project Creation Time, the info is available using

```
gcloud projects describe <project_id>
```

--format option can help output only this value, e.g:

```
gcloud projects describe <project_id> --format="value(createTime)"
```